# Image on cube face with correct perspective - three.js

Tags: three.js

I am displaying a picture on a face of a cube, but unfortunately the image is not projected as expected. The picture has a distortion towards the center break in the triangulated face of the cube. [Please look at this image for a clear example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZClu7.png) The lines should be in a straight line.

How can I display a picture on the face of a cube without breaking perspective?

I am rendering using a `CanvasRenderer` for compatibility reasons.

Here is the relevant code (CoffeeScript):

```
scene = new THREE.Scene()
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, windowWidth / windowHeight, 1, 1000)
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer()
renderer.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10)
materials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load('./grid.gif')})
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x0000AA})
    # ...
]
faceMaterial= new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)
cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, faceMaterial)
scene.add(cube)
renderer.render(scene, camera)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an artifact of `CanvasRenderer`. The best you can do is tessellate your geometry. For example,

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10, 4, 4, 4 );
```

three.js r.75

Comment: ahh i didn't see this coming this is right. but by artifact what it means this is new for me.

Answer (score -1):

No idea what crazy things goes your end.

Its seems your faceVertexUvs are not correct for the geometry but this should not happen anyways check this code it could be solution for your problem.

```
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 400;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff,0xffffff,1.0))


            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );

            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg" );
            texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:0xff0000  } );
            var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:0x00ff00  } );
            var material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {  map:texture } );
            var material4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:0xffff00  } );
            var material5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:0x00ffff  } );
            var material6 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:texture  } );

            var material = [ material1,material2,material3,material4,material5,material6]

            var mat = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(material);
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );

            scene.add( mesh );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```